# Trying to get my "load more" button to load 5 sliders at a time

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show 5 sliders at a time, so that when you click the Load More button 5 more will display. I also don't want the alert, I just want the load more to disapear. Unfortunately all my sliders stay hidden and the button doesn't work. here's what I have...

In my CSS:

```
.container {
display: none;
}
```

My HTML are 15 divs with the sliders in them and at the bottom is the load more button:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>​
```

My jquery is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".container").slice(0, 5).show(); // select the first five
$("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
    $("container:hidden").slice(0, 5).show(); // select next 5 hidden divs and show them
    if($(".container:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
        alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
    }
});
```

});​

Comment: do you get any errors? is that block of javascript inside a document.ready block?

Comment: The funny thing is it's working fine here... http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bEdfX/

Comment: in the jsFiddle you are using a document.ready block, instead of setting up a handler for the window's load event

Comment: Thanks MrOBrian sorry but unfortunately I'm a bit of a novice with jquery and I'm not quite sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Actually, looking at how jsFiddle constructs the page, they put your code inside a `$(window).load` block, so maybe that doesn't matter so much.  I'm still wondering if you are getting any errors. That's always the first place to look when javascript doesn't run.

Comment: Hello, nope not getting any errors.

Comment: There must be something else wrong then. As you've shown, your code does work in jsFiddle, so you'll need to figure out the differences between the code on your page and the code you put in jsFiddle. If you don't get any errors in the console, and your code doesn't run, then it's never even being executed.

Comment: I had just got an "syntax error: illegal character" at the closing of the script });​ Not sure why though.

Comment: There are any number of reasons you could get that error on that line. Either too many or not enough `}` or `)`, or some other line somewhere before that line not being written correctly, a stray comma... basically, there's something wrong somewhere in your code, and that's why it's not working.

Comment: I went in and just retyped the }); and now it works haha. Thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 0):

If container is holding all of the information you want, then nowhere are you changing it's css to be anything but display:none. This means that no matter what content is in there, nothing is going to be shown. And if you do not want the alert, just delete it? I don't quite understand that part.